# Sending AJAX request without querystring parameters as 'referrer'

Tags: ajax, google-calendar-api, referrer

I'm trying to communicate to Google Calendar API.
The API only accepts requests from a specific referrer, e.g.: www.mysite.com/calendar/events.asp

But sometimes the URL includes querystring parameters, e.g.:
www.mysite.com/calendar/events.asp?message=eventAddedSuccessfully&id=50

The API rejects requests from the above URL, and returns this message: 
"The referrer www.mysite.com/calendar/events.asp?message=eventAddedSuccessfully&id=50 does not match the referrer restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."

How can I send an AJAX request with only the path in the URL as the referrer?

Thanks

Comment: That is indeed a bind that may require some ugly workaround (like storing stuff in a cookie, then redirecting to the „correct“ URL). Ugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your restriction to cater the context path of the domain, it may be specific to that page (and possibly treats it differently with parameters) and causes the issue you're encountering.

```
www.mysite.com/*
```

or

```
www.mysite.com/calendar/*
```

Hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Indeed Google's API can be set to accept requests from HTTP referrers (web sites) with asterisks for wildcards.. I changed it to www.mysite.com/calendar/*, but it takes up to 5 minutes for settings to take effect.

Comment: Yes, its indicated on the Developer Console that it may take a few minutes for the changes to take effect. Good to hear its working!